# undefined variable from (this) jquery

Tags: jquery, undefined

Basically, I can't figure out why it isn't working...
The function is NOT wrapped inside the document.ready,

my function:

```
function expandImg(){
                var imgsrc = $(this).attr("src");
                $("#expander").css("display","block");
                $("#expander").html("<div class='close' id='close'>X</div><br /><img src='"+imgsrc+"' />");
    }
```

and html:

```
<img src='/pgal/".$galeryresult."' / onClick='expandImg()'>
```

Note: **$galeryresult** is a working src variable that outputs the actual image, but when I click on it, I get undefined in `src` .. why?

Note 2: `$(this)` is a **must** here as I'm outputting more different imgs from one `while fetch` code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're calling `expandImg`, `this` will be the global object, because you're just calling it directly: `expandImg()`. In JavaScript, when you call a normal function like that, in loose mode `this` during the call will be the global object (`window` on browsers); in strict mode, `this` during the call will be `undefined`. I don't *think* you can ever enable strict mode in `onXyz` attributes, so I think it would always be the global object.

You'd have to either use `call`, change your function, or (probably best) use modern event handling.

1. Using call:

```
onclick='expandImg.call(this)'
```

2. Changing your function:

```
onclick='expandImg(this)'
```

...then use the argument you're passing in instead of `this`:

```
function expandImg(img){
            var imgsrc = img.src; // Or $(img).attr("src"), but there's no need
            $("#expander").css("display","block");
            $("#expander").html("<div class='close' id='close'>X</div><br /><img src='"+imgsrc+"' />");
}
```

3. Using modern event handling:

Don't use `onXyz` attribuets at all, instead hook up the function with jQuery:

```
<img src='...' id="gallery-result">
```

then

```
$("#gallery-result").on("click", expandImg);
```

(You don't have to use an `id`, you can use any CSS selector.) Ensure that the code runs once the element exists (or look into *event delegation*).

Here's an event delegation example:

```js
$(document.body).on("click", ".foo", function() {
  alert("src: " + this.src);
});
```

```html
First image:
<div><img class="foo" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b51b0bf2dc8fb2091865cba7264b89d4?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"></div>
Second image:
<div><img class="foo" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ca3e484c121268e4c8302616b2395eb9?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG"></div>
Click each of the above.
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That's using `document.body`, but there's usually a container nearer to the group of elements that you can use to be more targeted.

Comment: 2nd didnt work, but .call did the work. BTW, I can't assign the onclick event on img through class or id, because all images has the same class, and they are pulled out of database automatically, that's why I wrote that the "this" function is a must here, though, thanks for your help

Comment: @StevenDropper: The second works just fine, if you note the "...use the argument you're passing in instead of `this`". (I've expanded that in case it was unclear.) If all the images use the same class, a class selector would work; for what you're describing, I'd probably use a class selector with event delegation. I added an example of that as well.

Comment: Ah I got it now. Okay thanks for your help, have a great time

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a class with the img? This should work with dynamically loaded content also.

```
<img class="exp" src='/pgal/".$galeryresult."' />

function expandImg(){
    $(document).off('click', '.exp').on('click', '.exp', function() {
        var imgsrc = $(this).attr('src');
        $("#expander").css("display","block");
        $("#expander").html("<div class='close' id='close'>X</div><br /><img src='"+imgsrc+"' />")
    });
}
```

Answer (score -3):

when you call the method in the `onClick` attribute, no object reference is passed, if you would like to pass the reference, put it on the args:

```
<img src='/pgal/".$galeryresult."' / onClick='expandImg(this)'>
```

and then:

```
function expandImg(input){
                var imgsrc = $(input).attr("src");
                $("#expander").css("display","block");
                $("#expander").html("<div class='close' id='close'>X</div><br /><img src='"+imgsrc+"' />");
    }
```

EDIT:

if you wouldn't like to change your method (keeping the $(this)), you should handle by jquery:

```
<img src='/pgal/".$galeryresult."' / id="image">
```

JS:

```
$("#image").on("click", expandImg);
```

now the function have the `this` reference inside

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It may not be ideal, but it works just fine and is the minimal change required to make the OP's code work.

Comment: You should have explained how inline event handling is messing up `this` scope. Using jQuery's event methods, `this` would have worked perfectly fine with no param needed

Comment: In the example case, he is using native `onclick`

Comment: It was downvoted because some perfect engineer with the best practices wants to show the best ways of the world and smash the alternatives haha